# is it possible to paste data from .CopyFromRecordset into sepcific cells

Tags: excel, vba

hello everyone :) Is it possible to paste data from .CopyFromRecordset into multiple specific cells? in my example SQL query returns 20 rows and

i want to paste 5 rows  into
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A7").CopyFromRecordset rst

next 6 rows into
Sheets("sheet1").Range("A13").CopyFromRecordset rst  etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. Just do something like:

```
n = 7
Do until rst.eof
Sheets("sheet1").cells(n, "A").CopyFromRecordset rst, 5
n = n + 6
loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem!:)

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at using `GetRows` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15